# angularjs ng-show="true" but still has class="ng-hide"

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I wanna see a div when I put the mouse over an image and remove it if I leave the mouse, with the ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave. But when I load my page, in the div appear class="ng-hide".

My code:

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-side" role="navigation" ng-app="panel" ng-controller="panelController">
        <div class="sidebar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav" id="main-menu">
                <li class="text-center">
                    <img ng-mouseenter="inProfile()" ng-mouseleave="outProfile()" src="{{ asset('image/id1.jpg') }}" class="user-image img-responsive"/>

                    <div ng-show="panelController.evento">
                        Hi!!
                    </div>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a  href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-3x"></i><span class="text-20">Dashboard</span></a></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  href="ui.html"><i class="fa fa-users fa-3x"></i><span class="text-20">Usuarios</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="tab-panel.html"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o fa-3x padding-left-10"></i><span class="text-20 padding-left-10">Emprendedores</span></a></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  href="chart.html"><i class="fa fa-money fa-3x"></i><span class="text-20">Inversores</span></a></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  href="table.html"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-3x"></i><span class="text-20">Noticias</span></a></a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </nav>

    <script>
        var tfc = angular.module('panel', []);

        tfc.controller ( 'panelController' , [ '$scope' , function($scope){

            $scope.inProfile = function(){
                $scope.evento = "true";
            }

            $scope.outProfile = function(){
                $scope.evento = "false";
            }
        }])
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is on page load `eventto` value is undefined that's why `ng-show` expression is hiding value on page load. you should define `evento` value to `true` to show it. You could this do from controller or also you could use `ng-init="panelController.evento=true"` on view

And make sure, you should use boolean rather than string which is used for expression evaluation in `ng-show`.

**Code**

```
var tfc = angular.module('panel', []);

tfc.controller('panelController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.inProfile = function() {
        $scope.evento = true;
    }

    $scope.outProfile = function() {
            $scope.evento = false;
    }
    //init values
    $scope.evento = true;
}]);
```

**Update**

You should directly access value of scope variable on view as you are not using `controllerAs` in you application, it should be `evento` instead of  `panelController.evento`

**Markup**

```
<div ng-show="evento">
   Hi!!
</div>
```

Comment: @CarlosSierra now what exactly problem you are facing?

Comment: When I load my page, this is the result:                                                           <div ng-show="false" class="ng-hide">
  Hi!!
</div>   and when I put the mouse over the image <div ng-show="true" class="ng-hide">
  Hi!!
</div>